# Scrollbar not appearing on custom Panel

Tags: java, swing, scrollbar

I have made a class `RefreshablePanel` that extends `JPanel`

```
public class RefreshablePanel extends JPanel {

static String description="";
static int x=10;
static int y=11;
    
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       super.paintComponent(g);
    for (String line : description.split("\n"))
        g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
void updateDescription(String dataToAppend){
        description = description.concat("\n").concat(dataToAppend);
        System.out.println("The description is "+description);
   }   
}
```

and then I am adding it into my **GUI_class** like this

```
JScrollPane scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane_2.setBounds(32, 603, 889, 90);
frmToolToMigrate.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_2);

descriptionPanel = new RefreshablePanel();
scrollPane_2.setViewportView(descriptionPanel);
descriptionPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
descriptionPanel.setLayout(null);
```

I have added the scrollbar in the class where I am making an instance of RefreshablePanel but scrollbar is not appearing.
I have tried adding

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 1010);
}
```

to refreshable Panel but then the string is disappearing like this
[image]

and nothing is appearing when I scroll down

Comment: Why does that code use custom rendering as opposed to displaying the text in a `JTextArea`?  BTW - `scrollPane_2.setBounds(32, 603, 889, 90);`  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: I have encountered a lot of problems with null layout manager . I would keep that in mind next time I design a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're using `null` layouts, so nothing is going to work the way it should.  Swing is designed at the core to utilise layout managers.
2. You're `RefreshablePanel` has no discernible size, meaning that when you add to the scroll pane, the scroll pane is likely to simply think it's size should `0x0`.  `RefreshablePanel` needs to provide some kind of size hint back to the scrollpane, preferably via the `getPreferredSize` method
3. You could use a `JLabel` (with text wrapped in html) or a non-editable `JTextArea` to achieve the same results

**Updated**

Take a quick check of your code.  You are declaring the `x` and `y` values as `static` and you are incrementing the `y` value in your `paintComponent` method

```
static int x=10;
static int y=11;

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
   super.paintComponent(g);
    for (String line : description.split("\n"))
        g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
}
```

This means two things.

1. If you have more than one instance of your `RefreshablePanel` they will ALL share the same `x`/`y` values AND update them
2. `y` is constantly being update to a new position, so if the panel is painted twice, on the second paint, the `y` position will start from the position it was last at when the first call exited.

Remember, you don't control the paint process.  A paint cycle may be executed at any time that the system decides it needs to...

Make the `x`/`y` values local variables to the `paintComponent` method...

**Updated**

The scroll pane will try and match the preferred size of the component if the available space allows for it.  This may mean that the scroll bars may not appear until you resize the window...but you're using a `null` layout so that won't work for you...

To affect the size of the scroll pane, you can use the `Scrollable` interface instead...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Scrollable01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Scrollable01();
    }

    public Scrollable01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                RefreshablePanel pane = new RefreshablePanel();
                pane.updateDescription("1. You're using null layouts, so nothing is going to work the way it should. Swing is designed at the core to utilise layout managers.");
                pane.updateDescription("2. You're RefreshablePanel has no discernible size, meaning that when you add to the scroll pane, the scroll pane is likely to simply think it's size should 0x0. RefreshablePanel needs to provide some kind of size hint back to the scrollpane, preferably via the getPreferredSize method");
                pane.updateDescription("3. You could use a JLabel (with text wrapped in html) or a non-editable JTextArea to achieve the same results");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(pane));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RefreshablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public String description = "";

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 1010);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int x = 10;
            int y = 11;
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (String line : description.split("\n")) {
                g.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
            }
        }

        void updateDescription(String dataToAppend) {
            description = description.concat("\n").concat(dataToAppend);
            System.out.println("The description is " + description);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 64;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 64;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was really great, how did you pick that. I made the variables local and that solves one of my problem of the text not appearing properly. But the scrollbar is still not appearing.

Comment: Should I dynamically change the size of the panel using setpreferred method to be as long as Y ??

Comment: @MAD_ABOUT_JAVA Yes, but that should be done in `updateDescription` if possible.  You will also need to revalidate the container to ensure that the scroll pane will try and re-lay it out...

Comment: I just saw the edit, thanx man , that's awesome , that was exactly what I was trying to do.